# Mysql REGEXP 2 words -- Same as AND LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like, regular-language

I have

```
SELECT p.*, gc.*, g.*, m.*, b.*
FROM (products AS p)
LEFT JOIN merchants AS m
    ON m.merchantId = p.merchantId
LEFT JOIN brands AS b
    ON b.brand = p.brand
LEFT JOIN groups_content gc
    ON p.brand = gc.brandsSelect
LEFT JOIN groups g
    ON g.group_id = gc.group_id
WHERE `p`.`percentOff` > gc.percent_off
    AND `g`.`group_active` = 1
    AND `p`.`price_sale` BETWEEN gc.price_min
        AND gc.price_max
    AND `gc`.`group_content_id` = '180'
    AND `p`.`keyword` LIKE '%women%' AND `p`.`keyword` LIKE '%jacket%'
    AND `p`.`status` = 1
ORDER BY p.price_sale ASC
```

this return me **158 results**

Also I have

```
SELECT p.*, gc.*, g.*, m.*, b.*
FROM (products AS p)
LEFT JOIN merchants AS m
    ON m.merchantId = p.merchantId
LEFT JOIN brands AS b
    ON b.brand = p.brand
LEFT JOIN groups_content gc
    ON p.brand = gc.brandsSelect
LEFT JOIN groups g
    ON g.group_id = gc.group_id
WHERE `p`.`percentOff` > gc.percent_off
    AND `g`.`group_active` = 1
    AND `p`.`price_sale` BETWEEN gc.price_min
        AND gc.price_max
    AND `gc`.`group_content_id` = '180'
    AND `p`.`keyword` REGEXP 'women.+jacket'
    AND `p`.`status` = 1
ORDER BY p.price_sale ASC
```

This should return me same result like previous. But returns me just **17 results**. What I am doing wrong?

### ----------

AFTER MANY SEARCHES here it is the right REGEXP

```
AND p.`keyword` REGEXP '^(.+jacket.+women.+)|^(.+women.+jacket.+).*$'
```

Comment: here it is the right REGEXP AND p.`keyword` REGEXP '^(.+jacket.+women.+)|^(.+women.+jacket.+).*$'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex and like are not equivalent statements:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(keyword VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO tab(keyword)
VALUES ('jacket for women');

SELECT *
FROM tab p
WHERE  `p`.`keyword` LIKE '%women%' AND `p`.`keyword` LIKE '%jacket%';
-- jacket for women

SELECT *
FROM tab p
WHERE p.`keyword` REGEXP 'women.+jacket';
-- (empty)
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b73ae/5/0)**</kbd>

`"woman"` anywhere in string and `"jacket"` anywhere in string

vs.

`"woman"` at the beginning, then any characters then `"jacket"` at the end

**EDIT:**

> But How do I get -- "woman" anywhere in string and "jacket" anywhere
>   in string --- using regular expression?

One way is to use:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE keyword REGEXP '.*women.*'
  AND keyword REGEXP '.*jacket.*';
```

I am sure there exists one regex for this case.

Comment: Got it . Thank you.  But How do I get -- "woman" anywhere in string and "jacket" anywhere in string --- using regular expression?

Comment: Now I am getting the right result. Thank you very much. I just need this in one REGEXP. Thanks again ...